# How to save the Password in C# .NET?

Tags: c#, database

I am making a C#.NET application wherein I have designed an Administrator account. Now to Login in that account the Administrator has to enter the password.

My Question is  : How do I save that password?

Possible options :

1. Global variable (Obviously incorrect because it will be reset to its default value everytime I run the application)
2. Database Relation (Feasible but it serves to be a scalar relation only....)

I don't want to store it in a scalar relation because I think it is stupid to use a relation for only one entry and one column!

Is there any other optimum way to store the password?

Comment: When the Administrator needs to login, I will ask him for the password. I will have the correct password stored(in some form). Then I will check if the two passwords match. If Yes, I will allow the Administrator to access his account. If Not, Error. It is analogous to us logging into our facebook(or any other) accounts.

Comment: Firstly: you have already explained why (1) doesn’t work – so why mention it at all? Secondly: **Never store a passeword!** Full stop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can store it salted and hashed in a user settings file.

You can access the default settings file using something like:

```
private bool CheckPassword(string salt, string password) 
{
   var hash = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(salt + password);
   var sha1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
   var sha1hash = sha1.ComputeHash(hash);
   var hashedPassword = ASCIIEncoding.GetString(sha1hash);

   return (Properties.Settings.Default.adminPass == hashedPassword);
}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for your Help...... Its very nice and warming to get great advice and tricks from experiences people like you all....

Answer (score 5):

For security reasons I would recommend you to store only the [hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) of the password and never the clear text password. You could store it in any persistent media you find it convenient: file registry, database, ...

Answer (score 3):

Do you have a database in your system already ? Then just put it there. You will probably have a users table, that can be extended to accomodate the password (?) If not, you could store it in a file.

What really matters, is that you should not store the password in plain text. It is bad security practice. You should one-way hash it using a good hashing algorithm (such as SHA512), preferably using a salt.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this is to persist the user's credentials on the server: store a hash of the password in the database. Ideally, you should compute and store something like `SALT + sha1(SALT + password)` where SALT is some random string computed for each password stored.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what everyone has been saying about not *storing* a plaintext password, you shouldn't *work* with a plaintext password in a string (for example, when getting the value from a text box).

This is because strings can remain in memory for an unknown, uncontrolled length of time.

They should be stored using [SecureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring.aspx).

In the way of explanation:

> An instance of the System.String class is both immutable and, when no longer needed, cannot be programmatically scheduled for garbage collection; that is, the instance is read-only after it is created and it is not possible to predict when the instance will be deleted from computer memory. Consequently, if a String object contains sensitive information such as a password, credit card number, or personal data, there is a risk the information could be revealed after it is used because your application cannot delete the data from computer memory.

Comment: While true, there are analysis tools that can read SecureString values (rendering it rather pointless), and if your machine is compromised to the point that memory debug tools are an issue, you are ***already compromised*** - so again, this solves little.