# How to Create an Automatic login in windows form application?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a windows form application which starts when computer is started. Now i want that when first time a user logins than it must save password somewhere and than next time it
must automatic login when computer is started.
Can Any body help me out in this issue???
Please Help..
Thanks in Advance

Comment: This goes against all tenets of Windows authentication, and would never be allowed.

Comment: Hash it and then put it in the registry.

Comment: But i saw it in an another windows form application. doesn't it have any other option???

Comment: I'm not I understand your need. Do you need Windows Log in automatically or just your app log in automatically when user open his session ?

Comment: @Brandon.Staley Can u tell me exact procedure?? i am new at it

Comment: @Floc i need my windows app Log in automatically.

Comment: You can have a checkbox and when once time the user selected that you save in your application the login... just it. In your initialize application you check if have the login save

Comment: Look for a hashing algorithm, there are plenty out there. Then you can store your hash in the registry like so http://stackoverflow.com/a/5927186/2171266 . When you read the data back out just decrypt it and log in. Or use @Floc's answer.

Comment: @MayogaX and how will i save login details??

Comment: @user3346501 in the properties of aplication...btw,depends on your strategy and data security. See exemple in http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/86503/Saving-the-state-serializing-a-Windows-Form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand, you want to do this :

At first login :

```
Properties.Settings.Default["Username"] = "test";
Properties.Settings.Default["Password"] = "password";
```

And after, just read previous settings :

```
var user = Properties.Settings.Default["Username"];
var password = Properties.Settings.Default["Password"];
// Then call your login method
```

Concrete application :

```
public bool Login()
{
    var username = Properties.Settings.Default["Username"];
    var password = Properties.Settings.Default["Password"];

    if (username == null || password == null)
    {
        // Ask the user to login
        var user = LoginWindow.AskForLogin();
        // If user login
        if (user != null)
        {
            username = user.Username;
            password = user.Password;
            Properties.Settings.Default["Username"] = username;
            Properties.Settings.Default["Password"] = password;
        }
    }

    // Log your user
    return Authenticate(username, password);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6563269/how-to-save-the-password-in-c-sharp-net). And [msdn answer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465069.aspx).
Also you can write password to [registry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.aspx):

```
Registry.SetValue(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\MyApp\", "Password", password);
```

And read it:

```
var password = Registry.GetValye(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\MyApp\", "Password", null);
```